# In a UniswapV3 pool, where do fees live?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

I'm trying to understand fees on UniswapV3. Not how to compute them (this has been well-covered and is not difficult to understand) but how they *actually* work in the code itself. The main question is: where do fees live?

The whitepaper in Section 3.2.1 states:

> In Uniswap v3, due to the non-fungible nature of positions, [fees deposited in the pool as liquidity] is no longer possible. Instead, fee earnings are stored separately and held as the tokens in which the fees are paid (see Section 6.2.2).

My question: held where?

Section 6.2.2 states:

> "Note that in Uniswap v3, fees are collected in the tokens themselves rather than in liquidity, for reasons explained in section 3.2.1."

This doesn't explain *where* or *how* they are held.

Is it the case that all the tokens in the contracts are not accounted for when computing liquidity? In other words, suppose we have an EHT-USDC pool and there is a swap of 1 ETH for USDC. The fee is taken in ETH and ETH is also deposited into the contract. Is it the case that only 0.997 ETH transferred is actually used in liquidity (in this pool, for instance) but 0.003 ETH is "reserved" for the fees, even though they're held in the same place?

From examining Collect and Swap events, it appears that this is the case but I'm unsure and want to be certain. Preferably someone can provide a trace that shows how this is the case.

I'm still learning Solidity so it's a bit hard for me to parse a project as complex as UniswapV3 at the code level. (Edited for clarity)